# Programmatically added tableRow does not show in TableLayout

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

I've created a TableLayout in a xml. Now I want to add a table row programmatically in my activitys' onCreate(). The method fillTable should do the job, but the TableRow doesn't show in the table.

Here is my code:

In the Activity:

```
    public void fillTable() {
    t1 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabelle);
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    TextView rang = new TextView(this);
    TextView mannschaftsname = new TextView(this);
    TextView spiele = new TextView(this);
    TextView siege = new TextView(this);
    TextView unentschieden = new TextView(this);
    TextView niederlagen = new TextView(this);
    TextView tore = new TextView(this);
    TextView doppelpunkt = new TextView(this);
    TextView gegentore = new TextView(this);
    TextView differenz = new TextView(this);
    TextView punkte = new TextView(this);

    rang.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    rang.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    rang.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
    rang.setText("0");
    rang.setTextColor(R.color.white);

    mannschaftsname.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    mannschaftsname.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    mannschaftsname.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
    mannschaftsname.setText("TEST");
    mannschaftsname.setTextColor(R.color.white);

    spiele.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    spiele.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    spiele.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
    spiele.setText("0");
    spiele.setTextColor(R.color.white);

    siege.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    siege.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    siege.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
    siege.setText("0");
    siege.setTextColor(R.color.white);

    unentschieden.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    unentschieden.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    unentschieden.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
    unentschieden.setText("0");
    unentschieden.setTextColor(R.color.white);

    niederlagen.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    niederlagen.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    niederlagen.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
    niederlagen.setText("0");
    niederlagen.setTextColor(R.color.white);

    tore.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tore.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    tore.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
    tore.setText("0");
    tore.setTextColor(R.color.white);

    doppelpunkt.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    doppelpunkt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    doppelpunkt.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
    doppelpunkt.setText(":");
    doppelpunkt.setTextColor(R.color.white);

    gegentore.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    gegentore.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    gegentore.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
    gegentore.setText("0");
    gegentore.setTextColor(R.color.white);

    differenz.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    differenz.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    differenz.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
    differenz.setText("0");
    differenz.setTextColor(R.color.white);

    punkte.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    punkte.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    punkte.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
    punkte.setText("0");
    punkte.setTextColor(R.color.white);

    tr.addView(rang);
    tr.addView(mannschaftsname);
    tr.addView(spiele);
    tr.addView(siege);
    tr.addView(unentschieden);
    tr.addView(niederlagen);
    tr.addView(tore);
    tr.addView(doppelpunkt);
    tr.addView(gegentore);
    tr.addView(differenz);
    tr.addView(punkte);

    t1.addView(tr, new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

show_table.xml:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tabelle"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/black"
android:stretchColumns="1" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tablle_tableRow1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_span="9"
        android:text="Liganame"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tabelle_tableRow2"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="1dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_rang"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_mannschaft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_spiele"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:text="Sp."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_siege"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:text="S"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_unentschieden"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:text="U"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_niederlagen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:text="N"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_tore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_span="3"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:text="Tore"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_differenz"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:text="Diff."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_punkte"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:text="Pkt."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tabelle_tableRow3"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rang"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mannschaft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:text="BBBBBBBBBB"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spiele"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:text="99"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/siege"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:text="99"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/unentschieden"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:text="99"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/niederlagen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:text="99"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:text="999"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/doppelpunkt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:text=":"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gegentore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:text="999"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/differenz"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:text="999"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/punkte"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:text="999"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Has your XML-Layout been inflated, adding a row will only work if the layout has been inflated previously

Comment: If you are going to add to the TableLayout programmatically, I don't think you need to add them to the XML Layout.

Comment: Right XML layout is static, programmatically build layout is dynamic and not connected to the XML

Comment: Okay, thank you. That probably solves my problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
    rang.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    mannschaftsname.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    spiele.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    siege.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    unentschieden.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    niederlagen.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tore.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    doppelpunkt.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    gegentore.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    differenz.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    punkte.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Remove the lines of code mentioned above, I was also having problem while doing this, then I removed these lines and the table shown dynamically...

This should work.

Comment: This works. Removed LayoutParams for `TableRow` children and it showed. Thank you :) Should be marked as answer.